# How to insert different selected value from drop down list into database

Tags: php, hidden

Scenario : The administrator is to assign different companies to different student. 
Problem : All student is given the same company of the last student in the form.

How do i make my hidden input work so that the correct selected drop down values of companies for each estudent to reflect correctly on the database?

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT student_id, admin_no, name, GPA, gender FROM student_details WHERE jobscope1= 'Information Technology' ORDER BY `GPA` DESC; ");
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT job_title FROM job_details WHERE jobscope='Information Technology' ORDER BY `job_title` ASC;");

            /*options sections start*/
            $options= '';
            while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
            {
                $options .='<option value="'. $row2['job_title'] .'"> '. $row2['job_title'] .'</option>';
            }
            /*options sections end*/

            //return the array and loop through each row
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {


            $adminno = $row['admin_no'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $gpa = $row['GPA'];
            $gender = $row['gender'];

                  echo "<tr>";
                  echo '<input type=hidden name=admin_no value='. $adminno . '/>';
                  echo "<td>" . $adminno . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $gpa . "</td>";
                  echo "<td>" . $gender . "</td>"; 
                  echo "<td><select name='ddl'  { myform.submit('') }'>".$options."</select></td>";
              }
                  echo "</tr>";
```

The php form action :

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE jobscope1 = 'Information Technology';");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 

  $complist = $_POST['ddl'];

$result4 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `student_details` SET `company`= '" . $complist . "' WHERE `jobscope1` = 'Information Technology';");
```

Comment: It's obvious many rows will be updated since you are not specifying in your `update` query for which student it should be updated for. Is `student_id` the primary key of `student_details`?

Comment: The admin_no is the primary key of student_details

Comment: One more question, currently is it updating as and when you pick an option from the dropdown? Or do you select values in multiple dropdowns and then submit?

Comment: @user007 We have to select values in multiple dropdowns and then submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//return the array and loop through each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $adminno = $row['admin_no'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $gpa = $row['GPA'];
    $gender = $row['gender'];

    echo "<tr>";
    //changed here (this is called an input array which makes it hold multiple 
    //values with same name)
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='admin_no[]' value='". $adminno ."'/>"; //edited
    echo "<td>" . $adminno . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $name . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $gpa . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $gender . "</td>"; 
    //changed here too
    echo "<td><select name='ddl[]' >".$options."</select></td>"; //edited
}
```

In your PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['ddl'])){
   foreach( $_POST['ddl'] as $index => $val ) //edited extra { here
   {
     $result4 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `student_details` 
                                    SET `company`= '" . $val . "' 
                                    WHERE `jobscope1` = 'Information Technology' 
                                    AND `admin_no` = '".$_POST['admin_no'][$index]."';");
   }
}
```

In this all your values will be updated (whether you changed any dropdown or not). If you want to limit only the changed dropdowns to be updated then you can have a hidden input variable which changes its value on change of dropdown and update your query only if the hidden input matches.

Comment: edited the necessary changes howere nothing is reflected on the database now.

Comment: how do you use the hidden input match that you mention? @user007

Comment: Let's discuss [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46670/specific-to-user-question)

Comment: i cant seem to discuss there... @user007

Comment: Alright never mind, could you please explain what happens when you submit the form? Any error messages shown? Does the page get refreshed? If it's only the `update` query not running, please try `echo mysqli_error($con);` after the update query;

Comment: this is what it shows when we echo mysqli_error($result4).
Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

Comment: Not `($result4)`. `mysqli_error()` takes connection parameter or just try `echo mysqli_error();`

Comment: this is what it says, after I echo mysqli_error();
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: lol >,< please try `echo mysqli_error($con);` $con NOT $result4

Comment: Can you `echo $val` and `$_POST['admin_no'][$index]` inside the `foreach` loop and see if anything prints? If it does, you need to test those values with your update query in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: when i `          echo $val;
          echo "<br>";
          echo $_POST['admin_no'][$index];` 
this came out 
`Deloite & Touche Management
2Oak 3 Films Pte Ltd (Sales Marketing Department)
1Promedia Directories
0Commonwealth travel service corporation Pte Ltd
4Oak 3 Films Pte Ltd (Sales Marketing Department)
4Commonwealth travel service corporation Pte Ltd
4`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46674/discussion-between-user007-and-angelica)